# Implement saving a number in a secure way on chain

Tags: solidity, blockchain, storage

There are a lot of questions like this, but before you close this one look closely.

Please have a look at this smart contract

```
contract StoreWithSecret {
    
    uint256 private secretNumber; 

    constructor(uint256 num) {
        secretNumber = num;
    }

    function isEqual(uint256 num) public view returns (bool) {
        return secretNumber == num;
    }
}
```

My goal with such a contract is to have a number or a string which will be UNKNOWN to everyone EXCEPT the person who created the contract. this contract is simple and of course you would like to hash it and everything, but that is details as i see it. Is it possible to implement such a behavior on a blockchain environment? Some answers stated i should encrypt it off-chain and then store the keys off-chain, though if you can provide a concrete example of how to do it, it could solve the problem.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just need to saved it and to prove the one sent on `isEqual` is the same, you could encrypt it on chain like so:

```
contract StoreWithSecret {
    
    bytes32 private secretNumber; 

    constructor(uint256 num) {
        secretNumber = keccak256(abi.encode(num));
    }

    function isEqual(uint256 num) public view returns (bool) {
        return secretNumber == keccak256(abi.encode(num));
    }
}
```

That way it remains hidden because:

1. The number is `private`.
2. There isnt a way to read `secretNumber` with any function. Meaning you dont have a function that `return secretNumber;`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and by any means if anyone obtains the abi or views the contract on chain he can not see this value?

Comment: That's not true. Anyone can read storage slot 0 of your contract to read `secretNumber`. Plus the constructor parameter will be present in the calldata of the tx that deployed your contract so it's still publicly available.

Comment: With that said, there is no way to store that secretly how i want it, right? can you provide some possible solution to this? @hroussille

Comment: Well you could send `keccak256(abi.encode(num))` as your constructor parameter for a start. That way the true value is never exposed on chain, only the hash.

Comment: @hroussille but having that hash on chain can one reverse the hash? i mean if the hash is exposed to everyone, you can use a brute force attack to try and guess the secret value, though it might be not practical and very much time consuming, but it's possible.

Comment: While it's not impossible to reverse it (as you said brute force is technically possible), it would take an incredible amount of time even if you were able to try billions of combinations per seconds. Hashes are built to be difficult (understand practically impossible) to reverse. You can read this : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/why-cant-we-reverse-hashes

Comment: I highly appreciate the answers here, Thank you. would you suggest that the provided answer is a secure enough one for an industrial implementation?

Comment: Was thinking about that and wondered, what are the chances that you give a value that is hashed the same as the secretNumber, but it's not exactly the secretNumber? a chance of collision also exists somewhere, however i think it's even more unlikely then brute forcing it.

Comment: if anyone is stumbling upon this, you can see the num argument in the creation onn etherscan, so i dont think its a viable option